# JS in Chrome extension - run a function whenever element enters DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Writing a Chrome extension.

When a particular type element enters the DOM (could be a class `.text-special` or a type of tag `<span>`, or an id `#searchResult` etc) I want JS to be able to recognize this and run a function on that element which takes the element itself as an argument.

I might scope it by saying "give me only elements that are children of this other element", but even then it's the same problem.

Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by element enters the DOM ? Is it added dynamically to the DOM ?

Comment: yes dynamically added via ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a MutationObserver https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/

Answer (score 1):

You should put the event to the parent and then check that the click was made on your child

```js
document.getElementById("parent").onclick=function(e){
  if(e.target.className=="child"){
    console.log(e.target);
  }
};
//test
document.getElementById("add").onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML+='<div class="child">123</div>';
};
```

```html
<div id="parent"><div class="child">abc</div></div>
<button id="add">add</button>
```

Comment: Nice except user isn't going to click on these elements. They just enter the DOM as a child of the parent. So that doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check almost continuously if the element has been added, you can choose an interval short enough and wrap the chrome extension in an IIFE.

```
var frequency = null;

    var readyStateFrequency = setInterval(function() {

        if (document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete") {

            clearInterval(readyStateFrequency);

            frequency = setInterval(function()   {
                app.executeMe();
            }, 10);
        }
    }, 10);

    var app;  if (!app) app = {};

    (function(callback) {

       var app = {

             executeMe : function(){

                          clearInterval(frequency);

                          // check if the DOM element exists(using selector query) and if found perform required logic
                          //this.doSomething();
             }
       };

    window.app = app;

    }(window));
```

Comment: This isn't very helpful - you're just polling the DOM. I'd like to set up a listener that gets called once and only once per potentially added DOM element that matches my query.

Comment: does the above code not work or you don't prefer the approach ?

Comment: jQuery .live and .bind methods are deprecated, so I am not sure about listening to the event.